# Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

> Given the function $2 \sin(2x+\frac{\pi}{2})$ find the amplitude, the period, the phase shift and the intersection points with the parent function, $\sin(x)$.

I was able to find the characteristics:

Period: $\pi$

Amplitude: 2

Phase shift: $\frac{\pi}{4}$

However I couldn't solve the equation $2\sin(2x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(x)$. My difficulty was those factors that multiply the sine and the variabel.

Answer (score 3):

Using $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a$ gives you
$$
2\cos 2x=\sin x.
$$
Now, using $\cos 2a=1-2\sin^2 a$ gives
$$
2(1-2\sin^2 x) =\sin x.
$$
The above can be written as
$$

4\sin^2 x+\sin x-2=0.
$$
This is a quadratic equation in $\sin x$. By the quadratic formula:
$$
\sin x={-1\pm\sqrt{33}\over 8 }.
$$
Then, for $x$ in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$
$$x=\arcsin({-1\pm\sqrt{33}\over 8 })$$
($x\approx .63487$ or $x\approx -1.003$).

Both of these are solutions to the original equation $2\sin(2x+{\pi\over2})=\sin x$.

Of course, there are other solutions to find...

Comment: Thanks.I missed the sum identitie.I suppose than $a=2x$ and $b=\frac{\pi}{2}$.